# Actual position of collapsed TreeViewItem on Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, visibility, treeviewitem

Is there a way to evaluate the actual position of a TreeViewItem on a Canvas if its Parent TreeViewItem is collapsed (meaning `<ParentTreeViewItem>.IsExpanded = false;`)? When debugging neither the Visibility nor the Position information of the collapsed item in the parent´s ItemsHost seems to be updated.

Appreciating any hint!

Cheers, Alex

Comment: What are you trying to do? Have you tried to force measure/arrange pass to get positions/sizes? Though I am not sure if Visibility matter or what results do you expect to get for collapsed items. It would be the best if you demonstrate that: *"neither the Visibility nor the Position information of the collapsed item in the parent´s ItemsHost seems to be updated"* with some code/xaml/screenshots..

Comment: Hi, actually I have two TreeViews on a canvas and connect their TreeViewItems by a line (connection). This works fine and the connection endings change their position if the TreeViews are pulled on the canvas. However if the parent TreeViewItem of the connected TreeViewItem is collapsed I would expect the connection end to move up to the collapsed parents height. But instead the connection end remains at hte prior expanded position - when I debugged I found that the position and visibility information of the child item is not updated when its parent items collapses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround for this problem:

Basically whenever a TreeViewItem fires an `OnCollapsed` or `OnExpanded` event I force all other TreeViewItems to determine their own position based on the `IsExpanded` property of their ancestors up to the tree root.

If any of the ancestors is collapsed (i. e. `IsExpanded == false`) I apply its position to the current TreeViewItems position.

If none of the ancestors is collapsed, I apply its own position (whereas position is a custom Point property of the TreeViewItem).

Code sample:

```
private Point DeterminePosition()
    {
        Point point = this.position;

        if (ParentTreeViewItem != null)
        {
            MyTreeViewItem parent = null, lastCollapsed = null;

            parent = ParentTreeViewItem;

            while (parent != null)
            {
                if (parent.IsExpanded == false)
                {
                    lastCollapsed = parent;
                }

                parent = parent.ParentTreeViewItem;
            }


            if (lastCollapsed != null)
            {
                point = new Point(position.X, lastCollapsed.Position.Y);
            }

        }

        return point;
    }
```